# Cassandra: where to modify opscenter agent for a newly added node to existing cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I have a single node Cassandra cluster on EC2 (launched from a Datastax AMI) and I manually added a new node which is also backed by the same Datastax AMI after deleting data directory and modifying cassandra.yaml. I can see two nodes in the Nodes section of Opscenter but I see Opscenter agent is not installed in the new node (1 of 2 agents are connected). It looks like in the new node it has its own opscenter installation and that somehow conflicts with the opscenter installation in the first node? I guess I have to fix some configuration file of opscenter agent in the new node so that it can point to the opscenter installation of the first node? But I can't find where to modify.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is stomp_interface section of /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf/address.yaml

Comment: You could’ve also used the “Fix” link near the “1 of 2 agents connected”, it’d reinstall and configure the agents on new nodes.

Comment: It didn't work in my case. I kept getting "Lost Connection" error :(

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually put stomp_interface into the configuration file. Also, I noticed that the process was looking for /etc/datastax-agent/address.yaml and never looked for /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf/address.yaml

Also, local_interface was not necessary to get things to work for me. YMMV.

I'm not sure where this gets set, or if this changed between agent versions at some point in time. FWIW, I installed both opscenter and the agents via packages.